# Extract value from an "array of string "in php

Tags: php

have an column named `'details'` in my `'abc'` table. This column is a string with different values .
eg:-

```
details[0]=( [Fruit : Mango][Vegetable : Potato][Color : Red] )
details[0]=( [Fruit : Apple][Vegetable : Brinjal][Color : Blue] )
```

Now i want only the Color Value from every column. How do i extract only  this specific value.
All rows have different values for the Color.

Comment: is the table an array?

Comment: @ShikharSubedi OP said `This column is a string with different values . `

Comment: @Salik well its not an array dude..

Comment: show the structure of your **abc** table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code.

```
$details = "( [Fruit : Mango][Vegetable : Potato][Color : Red] )";
echo str_replace('] )','',trim(str_replace(': ','',strrchr( $details, ': ' ))));
```

[**PHP Fiddle Demo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/je1-v46)

Comment: Table is not an array. One of the columns in that table is an combination of character. Its all combined.   @Salik : No details[0][2] wil give me 'r' of the 'Fruit'.

Comment: @Rinku i know you have mentioned that its string that why i have used `str` funtions

Comment: @Rinku salik answer give you `r` because you by doing [0][2] it will give you 3rd value from the string which is `r`

Comment: To be precise below is one of the values of the details column.[ ID : 62367][SVersion : 6.0.3][OVersion : 12.1.0.1][Platform : SOLARIS][OS : 11]  . I want only the Oversion values from the whole string,

Comment: What i exactly want is the Oversion value from each of the rows of the details column of the abc table.

Comment: @Rinku so just replace `: ` with `OVersion :` and see you will have your result

Comment: Hey the problem is . Few rows of the "details" column have a value missing. Eg: details[2]= ([SVersion : 6.0.3][OVersion : 12.1.0.1][Platform : SOLARIS][OS : 11])"; As v see the ID value is missing. In this case not able to retrieve the Oversion

Answer (score 0):

my bad, try this

```
$color=substr(details[0], strrpos(details[0], ":"),strlen ( details[0] ));
```